# cordova build failed : Android

Tags: android, cordova, gradle

I am trying to run my Cordova app on my android phone. I get the following error on build:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0hUTA.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQRgE.png)

In my Environment variables, 
Path is set to SDK, tools and platform-tools.
ANDROID_HOME to SDK and JAVA_HOME to JDK folder.

Answer (score 0):

You are under proxy. Command line can not access the Gradle URL.
You can open Application in Android Studio also.

Comment: I did try to run in Android Studio. I get the following error:


Error:Cause: startup failed:
script 'D:\tsem3\capstone\cordova\MyApp\platforms\android\CordovaLib\cordova.gradle': 1: unexpected char: 0x0 @ line 1, column 5.
   sEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDUsEDU